# Получение объектов через связь has_many :through. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, связи

Имею три модели:

User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :parties, through: :memberships
end
```

Membership

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :party
end
```

Party

```
class Party < ApplicationRecord
has_many :memberships
has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

Все вроде работает. Пользователи могут состоять в нескольких группах и в одной группе несколько пользователей.

Я добавил в **Membership** поле **Role**. Получается, пользователи могут иметь разные роли в разных группах. 
У меня есть объект **party**, из него я спокойно получаю нужного **user**, как правильно получить его роль? Я пишу что-то вроде:

```
m = user.memberships.find_by party_id: @party.id
role = m.role
```

Думаю, это неправильно, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Может тут фундатментальные ошибки присутствуют?

Comment: *Думаю, это неправильно* <- но это работает?

Comment: да, работает. Но это же костыль?

Comment: Возможно. Почему вы так решили?

Comment: Слишком много кода для rails. Я думаю, нужно что-то изменить, чтобы роль доставалась по user.role, например.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете определить метод `role`, возвращающий роль, на уровне модели `User`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :parties, through: :memberships

  def role(party)
    memberships.find_by(party: party).try!(:role)
  end
end
```

Тогда получить роль можно будет более элегантно

```
role = user.role(@party)
```

Comment: Да, действительно! То, что нужно! Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Писал примерно то же самое, но не успел :(
Маленькое дополнение: лучше не использовать `try`. Лучше добавить проверку `return unless in_party?(party)`

Comment: @anoam, что делает try и почему лучше сделать по-другому?

Comment: @MrAak Он проверяет не вызывается ли он в отношении объекта Nil-класса, если это так, то возвращает nil, если это другой объект - пытается вызывать метод, указанный в качестве аргумента. Так можно предотвратить вызов исключения (raise). Наверное unless или if тут будут действительно более уместны, чем try! или новый оператор &. . В этом случае вы сможете более точно и читабельно определить, что должно возвращаться методом, если связь не будет обнаружена.

Comment: @MrAak, что он делает уже написали. А не пользовать им лучше по тому, что он затрудняет чтение (как следствие - поддержку) кода, и понижает предсказуемость поведения.